# zip specific folders in git and put zip file to git

Tags: git, zip, put, back, subdirectory

I need to zip the files which are in git repository under the branch named A and inside path folder1/folder2. How can I zip and put it back to specific folder called folder 3 which is in in git again.

Answer (score 0):

```
git archive --format zip --output <path_to_folder_3>/<zipfilename> A:folder1/folder2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried :


could not create archive file 'Microservices/ProdBuilds_MicroServiceApps/Authentication/app.zip': No such file or directory

path to store zip file : 'Microservices/ProdBuilds_MicroServiceApps/Authentication


path to zip files : MicroServices/Authentication_MicroService

Branch : MS_Release.

Can you please help me to resolve. Is there any other way to zip files in git?? I tried to via shell script. Showing "Zip not found error" [linux platform]

Comment: show us the full command you're using.  and from your error message, i guess that either your path_to_folder_3 is not resolvable from the current working directory, or it doesnt exist. @Kalai

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to via shell script. Showing "Zip not found error" [linux platform]

That can happen when you use an invalid format (Zip) instead of a valid one (zip).

"[`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e9303dc8e7c5798b5b83f1c1dfccb875db06b29/Documentation/git-archive.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> mistakenly complained twice about a missing executable, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 1e4ea95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e4ea950f7a83240e15f5e77369cf700b94e8759) (29 Oct 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 3e9303d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e9303dc8e7c5798b5b83f1c1dfccb875db06b29), 08 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`archive-tar`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e4ea950f7a83240e15f5e77369cf700b94e8759): report filter start error only once
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> A missing tar filter is reported by `start_command()` using error(), but also by its caller, `write_tar_filter_archive()`, using die():
>
> ```
> $ git -c tar.invalid.command=foo archive --format=invalid HEAD
> error: cannot run foo: No such file or directory
> fatal: unable to start 'foo' filter: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> The second message contains all relevant information and even says that the failed command was intended to be used as a filter.
> Silence the first one because it's redundant.